# WPF MVVM Entity Framework - Datagrid data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I use EF 6.1.3 Datebase first; WPF App + MVVM Pattern + DataGrid control.

The database has a table: Task, InnerErrand, OutErrand.

Tables InnerErrand/OutErrand instructions are basically the same and differ only slightly. Table Task does not know anything about the Inner/Out, it does not have the keys of the Inner/Out. Such is the specificity of the essence. But the errands know what tasks they perform.
[Database Tables (MS SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoLMG.jpg)
Question: Is required for each out errand to display the task number, and if there are instructions Inner, also display it.

There DataGrid with data binding to the outer errand (OutErrand)

```html
<DataGrid x: Name = "dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
                               ItemsSource = "{Binding CV}"
                               SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedErrand, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"                             
                               >
                         <DataGrid.Columns>
        <! - Here you can see the out errand O1, O2, O3, O4, etc.  ->
                             <DataGridTextColumn Header = "out errand" Binding = "{Binding Number, Mode = TwoWay}" />
        <! - Here you can see the task number 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.  ->
                             <DataGridTextColumn Header = "task number" Binding = "{Binding Task.Number, Mode = TwoWay}" />
        <! - There must be displayed inner errand П1, П2, П3, П4, etc.  ->
                             <DataGridTextColumn Header = "inner errand" Binding = "{Binding Task.InnerErrand.Number, Mode = TwoWay}" />
                         </DataGrid.Columns>
                     </ DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```html
class ErrandViewModel: ViewModelBase
     {
         public ErrandViewModel ()
         {
             dbContext = new MyContext (); 
             LoadErrands ();  
   
    _cvs = new CollectionViewSource ();
             _cvs.Source = Errands;  // To filter
         }

    private void LoadErrands ()
         {
             var query = dbContext.OutErrand.ToList ();
             this.Errands = query;
         }
  
         public List <OutErrand> Errands
         {
             get
             {
                 return _errands;
             }
             set
             {
                 _errands = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged ();
             }
         }
   
         public OutErrand SelectedErrand
         {
             get
             {
                 return _selectedErrand;
             }
             set
             {
                 _selectedErrand = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged ();
             }
         }
        
         public ICollectionView CV
         {
              get
             {
                 return _cvs.View;
             }
             set
             {
                 _cv = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged ();
             }
         }
     } // End of class
 } // End namespace
```

The problem is that the inner errand is not displayed in DataGrid.

```html
<DataGridTextColumn Header = "inner errand" Binding = "{Binding Task.InnerErrand.Number, Mode = TwoWay}" />
```

It does not work at all. 
If change SelectedErrand:

```html
public OutErrand SelectedErrand
         {
             get
             {
                 return _selectedErrand;
             }
             set
             {
                 _selectedErrand = value;
                 MessageBox.Show (_selectedErrand.Task.InnerErrand.Select (x => x.Number) .First () ToString ().);
                 NotifyPropertyChanged ();
             }
         }
```

then the data is retrieved to MsgBox.
Tell me how to change the binding in the DataGrid, so that worked :)
Thanx for all :)